# Meteor, Angular, and Allow/Deny

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

So, I'm a little stumped. I've set up the Allow deny rules. But they don't work. And I've tried every variation I can think of. Right now, I have the bellow code block.

```
Players.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc){
        return true;
    },

    remove: function(userId, doc){

        console.log("REMOVAL!");
        return false;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier){
        console.log("FALSEHOODS");
        return true;
    },
});
```

That should disallow delete from that collection, correct? Or am I missing something. Right now, the update rule works great, but the removal rule doesn't even give me a message in the log.

Note: This is running on my server code right now. But I've tried it both server and client side.

Comment: Did you remove the insecure package?

Answer (score 1):

*Allow* rules are affirmative: *true* means *allow*.

Allow/deny rules should be under /server, not on client.

Comment: My rules are running on server. And its the remove rule that's not functioning correctly. As far as I can tell, its not even being hit.